# appcelerator 7.0.2 installation issue

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

after the installation of the appcelerator IDE V7.0.2 i got an error described above in the logs.
Config: osx 10.13.3, Node js V9.8.0, Java sdk : 8

I installed appcelerator CLI in first and it works fine.

I tried with different version of node and with Java 9, without success.

I uninstalled and reinstalled CLI and studi without success

Thank you.

```
## logs extract :

!SESSION 2018-03-20 17:53:19.443 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/oliviervinot/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/oliviervinot/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY VisualUI 4 0 2018-03-20 17:53:21.213
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: VisualUI [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.1.2.1512467051"; singleton:="true"
       com.appcelerator.titanium.core [30]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1512401448"; singleton:="true"
              com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core [31]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.msgpack-core
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.msgpack-core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1511010372"
                     org.msgpack-core [348]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core 4 0 2018-03-20 17:53:21.215
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core [17]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.0.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.1.2.1512467051"; singleton:="true"
       com.appcelerator.titanium.core [30]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1512401448"; singleton:="true"
              com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core [31]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.msgpack-core
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.msgpack-core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1511010372"
                     org.msgpack-core [348]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.360.soasta 4 0 2018-03-20 17:53:21.216
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.appcelerator.titanium.360.soasta [19]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.1.2.1512467051"; singleton:="true"
       com.appcelerator.titanium.core [30]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1512401448"; singleton:="true"
              com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core [31]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.msgpack-core
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.msgpack-core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1511010372"
                     org.msgpack-core [348]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.360.ui 4 0 2018-03-20 17:53:21.217
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.appcelerator.titanium.360.ui [20]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core; bundle-version="1.1.0.1512033598"; singleton:="true"
       com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core [17]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.0.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.1.2.1512467051"; singleton:="true"
              com.appcelerator.titanium.core [30]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1512401448"; singleton:="true"
                     com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core [31]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.msgpack-core
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.msgpack-core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1511010372"
                            org.msgpack-core [348]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

...
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.aptana.commandline.launcher.LauncherApplication, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Please try NodeJS 8.10.0 (LTS version) and check if the console command `appc info` will show any problems. But it looks like Studio is the problem (Eclipse is throwing the errors). CLI should run fine, so you could use Atom to start working. Do you have any other Eclipse installations on your machine?

Comment: i switched to n 8.10.0 and still have the error. I got no other Eclipse installations in my machine. Here is the appc info :

Comment: Titanium SDKs
  7.1.0.GA
 Version = 7.1.0
 Install Location = /Users/oliviervinot/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.1.0.GA
 Platforms  = iphone, android
 git Hash= df92fbf
 git Timestamp = 3/14/2018 20:46
 node-appc Version= 0.2.43
  6.2.1.GA
 Version = 6.2.1
 Install Location = /Users/oliviervinot/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.1.GA
 Platforms  = iphone, android, mobileweb
 git Hash= 301ffa4
 git Timestamp = 9/20/2017 00:52
 node-appc Version= 0.2.43

Comment: Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Version= 1.8.0_131
  Java Home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

Genymotion
  Path= not found
  Genymotion Executable = not found
  Genymotion Player  = not found
  Home= not found

Comment: VirtualBox
 Executable= not found
 Version= unknown

Android SDK
 Android Executable = not found
 ADB Executable  = not found
 SDK Path  = not found

Android NDK
0NDK Path  = not found
 NDK Version  = not found

Xcode
  9.2 (build 9C40b) - Xcode default
 Install Location = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
 iOS SDKs  = 11.2
 iOS Simulators = 11.2
 Watch SDKs  = 4.2
 Watch Simulators= 4.2
 Supported by TiSDK 7.1.0.GA = yes
 EULA Accepted = yes
 Teams= none

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your jdk version not with node version. Remove(delete created folder) installed java from path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ and then try to install appcelerator.dmg, it will automatically ask for download jdk and it will download required version of jdk.

Or Else, download this jdk version(1.8.0_131) and replace that jdk with this version. I hope it will help you.